# How to enable login functionality for elastic search & Kibana of Bitnami ELK Stack solution?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, bitnami

Below I provided both kibana vhost file. what changes I have to make so that kibana dashboard is username & password protected.

kibana-https-vhost.conf

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:443 _default_:443>
  ServerAlias *
  SSLCertificateFile "/opt/bitnami/apache/conf/bitnami/certs/server.crt"
  SSLCertificateKeyFile "/opt/bitnami/apache/conf/bitnami/certs/server.key"
  ProxyPass /elasticsearch http://127.0.0.1:9200
  ProxyPassReverse /elasticsearch http://127.0.0.1:9200
  ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:5601/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:5601/
  # HTTP Basic authentication layer
  <Location />
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Introduce your ELK credentials. If you have problems,.."
    AuthBasicProvider file
    AuthUserFile /opt/bitnami/kibana/conf/password
    Require user user
  </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

kibana-vhost.conf

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80 _default_:80>
      ServerAlias *
      ProxyPass /elasticsearch http://127.0.0.1:9200
      ProxyPassReverse /elasticsearch http://127.0.0.1:9200
      ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:5601/
      ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:5601/
      # HTTP Basic authentication layer
      <Location />
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "Introduce your ELK credentials. If you have problems, .."
        AuthBasicProvider file
        AuthUserFile /opt/bitnami/kibana/conf/password
        Require user user
      </Location>   
    </VirtualHost>
```

Comment: According to the documentation (https://docs.bitnami.com/virtual-machine/apps/elk/configuration/disable-kibana-auth/), the Kibana dashboard is password protected by default, and I have launched an ELK instance myself and confirmed that. Did you make any changes to your instance?

Comment: No, I didn't change anything. I read that document but i don't know why this is public by default.

Comment: Also, I have try this bitnami solution on GCP & Azure but in both case, the kibana dashboard is public by default.

Comment: I need to enable user & password in kibana dashboard not by apache in ELK Stack of Bitnami.